# reduce the time complexity of searching inside a list

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a function which basically finds the object using it's member variable.
Here's the code:

```
  RecipeModel returnRecipe(String? suggestion) {
    for (int i = 0; i < _appData.recipeCategories!.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < _appData.recipeCategories![i].recipes!.length; j++) {
        if (_appData.recipeCategories![i].recipes![j].recipeName! ==
            suggestion) {
          return _appData.recipeCategories![i].recipes![j];
        }
      }
    }
    return recipe;
  }
```

_appData is the object of a class which is responsible of fetching all the data once the app starts. [Here's](https://pastebin.com/wpGPnBNR) what inside of _appData.

_appData holds this entire json file.

What can I do to reduce the time complexity of the search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to reduce the time complexity, but you can use some functional programming to improve efficiency:

```dart
RecipeModel? returnRecipe(String? suggestion) {
  return _appData.recipeCategories
    // Put all recipes into the same iterable
    .expand((category) => category.recipes) 
    // Find the first recipe
    .firstWhere(
      // whose name is equal to the suggestion
      (recipe) => recipe.recipeName == suggestion,
      // If you don't find anything, return something else
      orElse: () => null);
}
```

Comment: I guess the time complexity would remain same if I store all the `recipemodel` from AppData in a list. Cause I would have to iterate over same number of recipeCatergories and them store each recipeModel inside a list right?

Answer (score 0):

Using single for loop you can also find result. time complexity will be O(n)

```
RecipeModel returnRecipe(String? suggestion) {
    int recCategoriesLen = _appData.recipeCategories!.length;
    int i = 0
    for (int j = 0; j < _appData.recipeCategories![i].recipes!.length;) {
        if (_appData.recipeCategories![i].recipes![j].recipeName! ==
        suggestion) {
            return _appData.recipeCategories![i].recipes![j];
        }
        j++
        if (_appData.recipeCategories![i].recipes!.length == j && i < recCategoriesLen - 1) {
            i++
            j = 0
        }
    }
    return recipe;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't reduce the complexity at all.  Ultimately it still iterates the same number of times (because it must still iterate over the same elements), but the code is now more convoluted.  Even though the original code has one `for` loop nested in another, it's overall still O(n) with respect to the total number of recipes.

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach, despite having one `for` loop nested in another, is  O(n) with respect to the total number of recipes.  You can't do better than that if you need to inspect every element.

If you care only about exact equality, then you could create a `Map<String, RecipeModel>` to map recipe names to `RecipeModel`s in advance.  Creating the `Map` will still be O(n), but each lookup will be O(1) instead of O(n).

Comment: Converting data into map taking same amount of complexity, doesn't make sense.

Comment: @ChandanKumar It doesn't make sense to create a `Map` on *every* lookup, but if the data rarely changes, then creating a *persistent* `Map` to do *many* lookups would be a win.  And in practice, data is accessed much more frequently than data is added.

Comment: it make sense, So it reduce comparison.